# PHP - Front controller pattern. One giant switch statement

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm using the front controller pattern in conjunction with a command resolver class, whose only function is to map requests from the view to a command object.

Everything works fine, but I'm starting to wonder if my implementation, which basically consists of a switch statement, is actually bad practice.

Would it be better practice to replace this switch statement with an XML file, or to map the requests physically to files in the command class (i.e. the request name would be the file name), or is a switch statement fine for this purpose?

Edit: I am using MVC, the front controller exists in the controller. This is more of a design pattern within a design pattern question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I actually am using MVC, the front controller is just a component of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using switch, you are hardcoding a lot. How about writting command function which will check possible array of files (possibly from cache which will be filled once by reading directory with files), and load a file if its ok.?

Answer (score 4):

Front Controller needs a **router class**, often used along with MVC design pattern.

To see how you can avoid `switch`, see this nice tutorial at phpro.org:

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

[Here is how the router is constructed in above tutorial.](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html#7)

Comment: Good suggestion. This may be a little tricky though because my application uses ajax really heavily, so not much is being appended to the URL.

Comment: @saddog: This should give you an idea though :)